# Filtering in count function - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have the following query which gives me the amount of referrals users have. However, I would like to only count the referral if the referred user has activated the premium plan. How could this be achieved?

Dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6700e27139167ffabfe3086c4848f6e5).

I am using PostgreSQL version 14.

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.premium,
COUNT(referrals.referrer) as referred
FROM users
LEFT JOIN referrals
ON users.id = referrals.referrer
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY referred DESC;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try to use [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html) clause or condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.premium,
  COUNT(referrals.referrer) FILTER(WHERE premium = true) as referred
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN referrals
  ON users.id = referrals.referrer
  GROUP BY users.id, users.email, users.premium
  ORDER BY referred DESC;
```

**Edit**

From you comment you I think you can try to use subquery to do aggregate function to find `premium` user first, then do `OUTER JOIN` for `user` table.

```
SELECT u.*,
       coalesce(referred,0) referred
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT f.referrer,
       COUNT(f.id) FILTER(WHERE u1.premium = true) as referred
  FROM users u1
  JOIN referrals f
  ON u1.id = f.id
  GROUP BY f.referrer  
) t1
ON t1.referrer = u.id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5685c8b4f901fed1d38b49e7442d2eaf)

Comment: This filters based on the referrer's premium status. I would like to filter the referred users based on their premium status. So the query should return id 1 having referred two users, and id 2 having referred one user.